# how to package JRE with jar file so as to run on Java independent machine

Tags: jar, java

I have to run my jar file on a machine which does not have java installed. I went through this link:
http://www.java.net/node/655012

but I dont know how to do it. Can anybody tell me the steps that are required to be done to achieve this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap with launch4j to get an EXE file or deploy with java Webstart to get a clickable link on a web page (which prompt you to install Java)

Comment: Thnnks Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. Other than launch4j, can we do something on our end to make this work without java being installed on the machine?

Comment: How can we set the path of Java.exe in the application which we are  running? (As given on the above link)